# reset counter for new date in php

Tags: php, jquery, php-5.6

**In php i have a code like :**

```
    $job_code = $request->get("job_code");
    $day      = date('d');
    $month    = date('m');
    $year     = date('y');
    $date     = $day.$month.$year;
```

using this i am getting format like :  abc-241018 
but i want the format like for date 24 oct : abc-241018-001 (001 to how many enteries may add in a day like 090)

second thing this counter should be changed or reset for the next day like on date change like 25 0ct : abc-251018-001 (001 to how many entries may add in a day like 090) .

it should be reset for new date how can i achieve this by php is there any best way to solve this ?? please help me related to this .

Comment: Are you maintain the counter value in database?

Comment: No not maintatining the counter value in db

Comment: Then how will you increment the counter value?

Comment: Unless you need those individual variables for other stuff later on, you might as well replace the last four lines with `$date = date('dmy');` …

Comment: Hi Ankita, Welcome to the Stackoverflow...!

I don't understand why are you calling the date() object multiple times. You can get date as per your desired in just a single line.

`date('dmy');`

Secondly, how you are maintaining the counter? how it get increased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a custom service to provide expected value, it can store nearest date it render a code. Then if date.now and previous date are different, you will reset the counter.

Answer (score 0):

date ("F d Y H:i:s.")

that should do the full date and time if you dont want the time remove the h i s. and that should give you the correct format which you have asked for.

have fun